# Some OSM tags in polygons and some in points - how to bring them together

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, osm2pgsql, geopackage

Tagging objects in OSM can sometimes be done as polygon or as point. For example [ruins](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:historic%3Druins) or [museum](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:tourism%3Dmuseum)

[image]

So far so good, but finding a specific object in a osm-dataset makes it necessary to look into the points AND into the polygons table.

For example: I want to display all museums in a city map. Some museums are  tagged as points, some as polygon:
[image]

I could import the centroids of the polygons into the point table. That will sometimes result in duplicates. Is there also a better way to solve that?

I'm using GeoPackage (ogr2ogr) or PostGIS (osm2pgsql) with QGIS 3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of getting around this is to use the **center** function in an Overpass query. ([Documentation here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Center).)

Normally, a query for museums gives us what you picture above: nodes as well as ways, depending on how the object exists in OSM. By appending `center` to your `out` statement, you'll get the centroid for the object.

Here is an example query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:stuttgart}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["tourism"="museum"](area.searchArea);
  way["tourism"="museum"](area.searchArea);
);
out center;
>;
```

And the output:

[image: linden museum center]

Even though the Linden Museum exists as a way, we get a node which represents its center. Upon converting to another GIS format, this will be included with the rest of the points.

A distinct advantage of this method is that the **center** function will also collapse relations to their centroids. It's possible that this could result in a centroid which is not located in any of the relation's parts, but does eliminate any potential duplicates.

You can try the query yourself [right here](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/IU8).

Comment: Okay, this will give me exactly the result I expected. But unfortunately I use PBF and import it into a GPKG with ogr2ogr (I need not just need museum, I need nearly everything in the dataset!) Overpass is limited.

Comment: Ah! Well, it sounds like you need something like *osmconvert*, which includes the command `--all-to-nodes`. It performs similarly to the Overpass *center* function, but can apply to a PBF. I'd write up another solution, but I'm not as experienced with using osmconvert. You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Dispose_of_Ways_and_Relations_and_Convert_them_to_Nodes).