# osmconvert --all-to-nodes returns same point count as the raw data has

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

According to this question [Some OSM tags in polygons and some in points - how to bring them together](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322492/some-osm-tags-in-polygons-and-some-in-points-how-to-bring-them-together) I used `osmconvert --all-to-nodes` to extract the central points of all ways and relations.

I used a osm.pbf as input:

```
osmconvert osm.pbf --all-to-nodes -o=osm_node.pbf
```

...or with increasing id:

```
osmconvert osm.gpkg --all-to-nodes --object-type-offset=10^15  -o=osm_node.pbf
```

and translated the resulting osm_node.pbf to GPKG with ogr2ogr.

The result is:

The RAW osm_node.gpkg:[image]

The "all-to-nodes" osm.pbf
[image]

The resulting GPKG should have a lot more nodes as the raw data has. But it hasn't...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many features do you find from .pbf with `ogrinfo -al -so osm.pbf`?  Do you know if `--all_to_nodes` transfers all tags unaltered to the new points?

Comment: Hm the result of `ogrinfo -al -so osm.pbf` for both files (RAW and Nodes) is: Feature Count: -1 for every geometry and relation...

Comment: osmconvert cannot process GPKG files, you are doing something wrong or your examples are wrong.

Comment: I convert the PBF to GPKG with ogr2org AFTER using osmconvert

Comment: Ok, GDAL does not support quick feature count with "summary only" because the only way to get if is to read the whole file. Only nodes with tags defined in osmconf.ini http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/data/osmconf.ini are considered as points by GDAL. I wonder if "all_to_nodes" keeps the tags as they are. For example tag "highway" should go to the point layer as well.